# Article(Product) is not showing in front which is created using API article

Tags: shopware

I have created one product using api of shopware.

Reference: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/api-resource-article/

This product(article) is listed in Item -> Overview of shopware. But when I edit this product and try to Preview this product(article) that How it looks in front, it does not show in front. It shows : 
Unfortunately, this product is no longer available.
 [image]

Can Someone help me why this product is not showing in front? I want to show the article in the front which I have created using API in my Plugin.

My array for insert article data in shopware is following.

```
$client->post('articles', 
    array(
        'name'             => 'Damen Organic T-Shirt',
        'description'      => 'Description',
        'descriptionLong' => 'Test Description',
        'active'           => 1,
        'taxId'            => 1,
        'metaTitle'        => '',
        'keywords'         => '',
        'changetime'       => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        'notification'     => 0,
        'supplier'         => 'Shirtee',
        'categories'       => 'Shopware',
        'mainDetail'       => array(
            'number'   => 'MO1C38Q',
            'inStock'  => 1,
            'weight'   => '1.000',
            'position' => '1',
            'width'    => null,
            'height'   => null,
        'attribute' => array(
            'attr1' => '',
        ),
        'prices' => array(
            array(
                'customerGroupKey' => 'EK',
                'price'            => 50,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'images'            => array(
        'link' => 'test.png'
    ),
    'configuratorSet'   => array(
        'groups' => array(
            array(
                'name'    => 'Size',
                'options' => 'M'
            ),
            array(
                'name'    => 'Color',
                'options' => 'Green'
            ),
        )
    )
));
```

Your answer will really help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is required to pass `active => true`  within `mainDetail` as shown in the [example](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/examples/article/):

```
    $minimalTestArticle = array(
    'name' => 'Sport Shoes',
    'active' => true,
    'tax' => 19,
    'supplier' => 'Sport Shoes Inc.',
    'categories' => array(
        array('id' => 15),
    ),
    'mainDetail' => array(
        'number' => 'turn',
        'active' => true,
        'prices' => array(
            array(
                'customerGroupKey' => 'EK',
                'price' => 999,
            ),
        )
    ),
);

$client->post('articles', $minimalTestArticle);
```

Following is the query that you can find within `engine/Shopware/Bundle/StoreFrontBundle/Service/Core/ProductNumberService.php -> isNumberAvailable`

```
SELECT variant.ordernumber FROM s_articles_details variant INNER JOIN s_articles product ON product.id = variant.articleID AND variant.active = 1 WHERE (variant.ordernumber = 'number') AND ((variant.laststock * variant.instock) >= (variant.laststock * variant.minpurchase)) LIMIT 1
```

Also, it is required to set `active => true` for each variation if you creating them.